Upload an image to WYSIWYG editor without using a submit button
I am currently making a WYSIWYG editor for a forum. I want users to be able to upload an image but want this done using AJAX as I want users to be able to add text and use formatting before they hit submit and upload the post.
When the PHP code is run I am having an issue where it's basically saying that the input is empty and it's not uploading any images.
Here is my HTML:
<input type="file" name="img" id="img" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif">
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>

and here is the AJAX I am using:
$('input:file').change( function() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("img", document.getElementById("img").files[0]);
    fd.append("submit", true);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploads/upload_img.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.success) {
                //Successfully uploaded
                var img = document.createElement("img"); // Create a new image element
                img.setAttribute("src", data.path); // Set the src attribute to the reference of the newly uploaded image. Note that we are referring to the uploaded image in our server
                $("#editor").append(img); // Append the image element
            }
        }
    });
});

And finally, here is the PHP:
<?php

session_start();

$response = ["success"=>false, "message"=>"Bad request"];

if(isset($_FILES["img"])) {
    
    $username = strtolower($_SESSION['username']);
    $username = str_replace(' ', '-', $username);
    
    $response["message"] ="Unknown error occurred";
    $target_dir = $username."/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            $response["message"] = "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            $response["message"] = "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $response["message"] = "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["img"]["size"] > 500000) {
        $response["message"] = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        $response["message"] = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $response["message"] = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $response["message"] = "The file ". basename( $_FILES["img"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            $response["success"] = true;
            $response["path"] = $target_file;
        } else {
            $response["message"] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>

For reference, $_SESSION['username'] is the user currently logged in.
The first if statement is being returned as false but can't see why. I've tried searching on here and using Google to look through several other posts to find the error I'm having but I am having no luck so don't want this post to be shut down as a duplicate.

You have no error. If it is not set, it is not set. Debug the $_FILES array and other parts of the request to immediately gain more insights instead of searching at other places out there in the interwebs.

never use user-input like the name of the user or the name of the file upload as actual names on the filesystem. especially not with file-uploads. this is extremely dangerous.

Is there a possibility for it to be set the way I am doing it? The var_dump is returning nothing.

that can't be. var_dump() is always returning something (at least null) and always outputting.

I get a return of [] and length of 0 so something ain't right. Is it because I am not using any sort of submit button? I want users to choose and image and then it gets appended to the editor and submitted to a database.

looks good, is just an empty array. what is $_POST?

You mean $_POST instead of $_FILES? Returns the same.

The form-data is empty. Check in browser first before submitting.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
